# 「まま」と「状態」が一緒に使われていることについて

Tags: grammar, word-usage, synonyms

次は「上級へのとびら」という教科書に出た文章です。テーマは国政の「[三バン](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%89%E3%83%90%E3%83%B3)」、すなわち「ジバン、カンバン、カバン」 です。

> また、議員を選ぶ側も、政治家の子供だから、有名人だからという理由だけで投票するといった態度を考え直す必要があると思う。今の**ままの状態**が続くと、将来、日本の政治はある一部の人達だけのものになってしまい、ますます国民から離れてしまう。

問題点は強調した「ままの状態」です。確か、「まま」という表現はもう「状態」の意味を含んでいるので、「まま」か「状態」のどちらかだけを使えばいいのではと思います。

> 今の状態が続くと

> 今のままに続くと

どうして両方の言葉が一緒に使われているのでしょうか。「ままの状態」とただ「状態」を使うことはどう違いますか。

Comment: Not an answer but your usage of のではないでしょうか feels a bit unnatural to me.

Comment: You mean 今のまま**が** (instead of に in the last quote)?

Comment: @JimmyYang absolutely, it should be でしょう without the ではない

Comment: @sundower I really meant  今のままに but it is a mistake, as Naruto pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

可能な表現は以下の通りです。

1. 今の状態が続くと
2. 今のままが続くと
3. 今のままの状態が続くと
4. 今の状態のまま続くと
5. 今の状態のままが続くと
6. 今のまま続くと

意味はほぼ変わりません。

「まま」はそのまま副詞として使われるので、「今のまま**に**続くと」は誤りです。（[「ままに」は違う意味](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%BE%E3%81%AB-mama-ni-meaning/)になります。）

「1 や 2 のように言えるのなら、わざわざ 3 や 4 のように言うのは冗長ではないのか」という質問だと思います。実際には「(連体形)ままの状態」「(連体形)状態のまま」は、いずれも非常によく使われる表現であり、特に冗長さは感じません。せいぜい、少し強調されて感じる程度です。

- まだ空は暗いままの状態だ。 / まだ空は暗い状態のままだ。
- 立ったままの状態で相談した。 / 立った状態のままで相談した。

「まま」には「状態」の意味を含む場合もあれば含まない場合もある、と考えるしかないと思います。

Answer (score 2):

「まま」は確かに「状態」の意味を含みますが、統語（シンタックス）上の機能は少し違います。「状態」が使える位置でいつも「まま」が使える訳ではありません。「状態」ほど名詞として自立していないと言うことができると思います。必ず他の言葉によって修飾されるという意味では「ため」のような形式名詞に近いです。

個人的には「今のままが続くと」は少し不自然だと思います。（もちろん、「今のまま」を標語のようなものだと理解して、「『今のまま』が続くと」と読むことはできますが。）

「今のままの状態」は、どのような「状態」であるかを「今のまま」で説明する構造と見ることができます。

> ［今のまま］の状態

もちろん「今の状態」と言うこともできますが、「今のままの状態」の方が「継続する」という意味が強調されます。ただし、今回の文では動詞の「続く」があるので、「まま」がなくても「継続する」という意味は表現できています。